# Why bosonic field operator in momentum space contains both creation and destruction operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, many-body

For fermionic field, the transformation from real space to momemtum space is a simple Fourier transformation $$\psi^\dagger(x)=\sum_{\mathbf{k}}c^\dagger_{\mathbf{k}}e^{ik\cdot x}$$ But in bosonic case, the field operator is 
$$\phi(x)=\sum_{k}\left[b^\dagger_{-k}+b_{k}\right]e^{ik\cdot x}$$
How does this difference come from? What's the physical significance of this difference?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You can pick any complete set of single particle functions $\{\phi_i(x)\}_{i=1,...,\infty}$ and $\Psi(x)=\sum_i b_i \phi_i(x)$, with $[b_i,b_j^\dagger]=\delta_{ij}$. Usually you then truncate the basis for any practical computation.

Comment: the reason for that expression of $\phi$ is not the bosonic statistic, but the realness of the field (or hermiticity of the field operator). A complex bosonic field would be written as $\phi^{\dagger}= \sum_{\alpha} c_{\alpha} a^{\dagger}_{\alpha}  $

Comment: Yes, the second equation is not the bosonic field operator. The analogous expression for bosons is $\Psi(x)^\dagger=\sum_k b_{k}^\dagger e^{ikx}$ using plane waves as basis functions (modulo normalization).

Answer (score 1):

$\def\bk{{\bf k}} \let\dag=\dagger$
I've never seen an expression like your first one.
For a fermion field I would write
$$\psi(x) = \sum_{\bk,s} \left(a_{\bk,s} u_{\bk,s} e^{-ikx} + 
                          b_{\bk,s}^\dag v_{\bk,s} e^{ikx}\right).$$
Leaving apart several details, $a_{\bk,s}$ is a destruction operator for a particle with momentum $\bk$ and helicity $s$, while $b_{\bk,s}^\dag$ is a creation operator for the corresponding antiparticle. Of course
$$\psi^\dag(x) = \sum_{\bk,s} \left(a_{\bk,s}^\dag u^*_{\bk,s} e^{ikx} + 
                   b_{\bk,s} v^*_{\bk,s} e^{ikx}\right)\!.$$

For a charged boson field a quite analogous equation holds, whereas for a neutral one, where particles and antiparticles coincide, you would have $a$'s in place of $b$'s.

Comment: OP is talking about a non-relativistic many body system, that's why the fermion field does not contain antiparticles.

Answer (score 0):

The Fermi field obeys $\{\psi(x),\psi^\dagger(x')\}=\delta^3(x-x')$ so we don't need both $a_k$ and $a^\dagger_k$ in the field $\psi(x)$ to get this from $\{a_k,a^\dagger_{k'}\}= \delta_{kk'}$ . For the bose field we need $[\phi(x),\partial_t \phi(x')]=i\delta^3(x-x')$ so we need both $b_k$ and $b^\dagger_k$ in the field to get a non-zero commutator.

Comment: I think this just pushes the question back to why we need that funny-looking commutation relation for a boson field but not a fermion field.

Comment: @tparker  Good point. I was thinking of phonons where $\Pi(x)=\dot \phi$ rather than Schrodinger bosons (such as helium atoms) where $\Pi(x)=i\phi$. In the latter case we need only $[\phi(x),\phi^\dagger(x')]= \delta^3(x-x')$ and $\phi$ has only $b_k$'s just like the fermi case,, and as explained by Kase above.

Answer (score 0):

The difference doesn't actually boil down to bosonic vs. fermionic. Instead, the two kinds of fields arise in different contexts. The former kind of field, which only contains a Fourier transform of one kind of ladder operator, typically arises in nonrelativistic situations where there are no antiparticles. The latter kind of field, which contains both a creation and an annihilation operator, tends to come up in relativistic situations, or in non-relativistic situations in which the effective field theory description has emergent Lorentz invariance and/or antiparticles. Either type of field can consist of either bosonic or fermionic ladder operators, but they're useful in different contexts and obey slightly different (anti)commutation relations.